# ValueOf() method of java.sql.TimeStamp class, returns unwanted output

Tags: java, date

When a String value with fractional seconds is passed to java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf() method , where the fractional seconds length is less than 6, the valueOf method adds trailing zeros which changes the value of the fractional string.

```
public class TimestampTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Timestamp t = Timestamp.valueOf("2005-1-01 10:20:50.11");
}
}
```

**valueOf - returns nano seconds as - 110000000 -** which is not the original value.

This should instead add leading zeros as done in case of toString() method.

I am expecting output **Just '11' or '000000011'**

Can someone tell me if my understanding is right or I am mistaking some where.

Comment: Seems OK to me, 0.11 seconds is 110000000 nano seconds.

Comment: Well, your understanding is wrong. It's a fraction of a second. 0.11 is 0.11, not 0.000000011.

Answer (score 2):

It is a fraction so function behaves right.

0.11 = 0.110000 not 0.000011

In other words, 0.11 seconds is indeed 110,000,000 nanoseconds.